# How to turn off pre-check of how many rows are in the resultset in logstash output

Tags: jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc, exasolution

I'm trying to turn off the pre-select logstash does to determine the count of rows, but ExaSol DB does not support any limits in any aggregation, is there any way to turn it off in logstash?

```java
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/jdbc/exajdbc6.0.15.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver"
    jdbc_user => "am_mon"
    jdbc_password => "XXXXX"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:exa:xxx.xx.xx.xx..xx:xxxx"
    jdbc_default_timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
#    schedule => "05 7 * * *"
    statement => "select local_date, LOCAL_HOUR, events from DWH_MON.V.M_EVENTS"

  }
}
```

Logstash Error Log:

> [2019-06-07T12:28:00,834][ERROR][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Java::JavaSql::SQLException: LIMIT not allowed in aggregated selects [line 1, column 127] (Session: 1635677142479452406): SELECT count(*) AS "COUNT" FROM (select local_date, LOCAL_HOUR, events from DWH_MON.V.M_EVENTS limit 1) AS "T1" LIMIT 1
>
> [2019-06-07T12:28:00,838][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#}

As logstash wants to see how many rows are to be expected it uses limit 1, but exasol can't process any limit on aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of LogStash, I guess. The `LIMIT 1` part is unnecessary and should not be there in the first place.

You may try to use SQL pre-processor to try to identify such queries and remove `LIMIT` manually. But maybe it's easier to patch LogStash itself.